# How to get the version information of a DLL file in C++

Tags: c++, windows, dll, version

I need to get the version information of a DLL file I created in Visual Studio 2008 C++. How do I get it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Thanks for the answers.

This worked for me:

```
WCHAR fileName[_MAX_PATH];
DWORD size = GetModuleFileName(g_dllHandle, fileName, _MAX_PATH);
fileName[size] = NULL;
DWORD handle = 0;
size = GetFileVersionInfoSize(fileName, &handle);
BYTE* versionInfo = new BYTE[size];
if (!GetFileVersionInfo(fileName, handle, size, versionInfo))
{
    delete[] versionInfo;
    return;
}
// we have version information
UINT                len = 0;
VS_FIXEDFILEINFO*   vsfi = NULL;
VerQueryValue(versionInfo, L"\\", (void**)&vsfi, &len);
aVersion[0] = HIWORD(vsfi->dwFileVersionMS);
aVersion[1] = LOWORD(vsfi->dwFileVersionMS);
aVersion[2] = HIWORD(vsfi->dwFileVersionLS);
aVersion[3] = LOWORD(vsfi->dwFileVersionLS);
delete[] versionInfo;
```

Comment: Any idea of how to do this on Mac??

Answer (score 9):

If you want programmatic access, see [Version Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646981(VS.85).aspx) in MSDN for the APIs and data structures you need.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you need to access the VS_VERSION_INFO resource; http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0498/c0498.aspx

Comment: You phrased it like the ms paperclip :) +1

Answer (score 0):

It should be there in the properties (version tab) when you open it in windows explorer