# How to read names and versions of assemblies

Tags: c#

I have to create an application to read the name of all DLLs (assemblies) in my application path along with its version. And also to read  the same of all the dll in the sub folders.

How to do this in C#. Can any one help me with sample code?

**EDIT** : how  to read details of Legacy dlls( External dlls- not created in .NET)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I removed the 'assembly' tag, because I think that's for questions about assembly language.

Comment: For legacy dlls: I've seen someone refer to using dumpbin.exe or dependency walker from .NET code, but I can't find an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should search through your given root directory by calling [`Directory.GetFiles()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx). You can run through the result and load every assembly by calling [`Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.reflectiononlyloadfrom.aspx) (cause if you load it that way it won't be added to the AppDomain, thous no unload is needed).

With these [`Assembly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbe1wdx9.aspx) classes you can access the [`GetName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3bk16ya.aspx) function and take a look into the [`Version`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.version.aspx) property to get the version information.

Other properties, that are not easily to get, can be reached through the [`GetCustomAttribute()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7s8054x.aspx) function like this:

```
((AssemblyCopyrightAttribute)assembly.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(AssemblyCopyrightAttribute), true).Copyright
```

With these informations you should be able to built up the list you like.

#### Update:

And here's the obligatory linq code sample:

```
var rootPath = @"C:\MyRoot\Folder";

var query = Directory.GetFiles(rootPath, "*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                     .Select(fileName =>
                     {
                         try
                         {
                             return Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(fileName);
                         }
                         catch
                         {
                             return null;
                         }
                     })
                     .Where(assembly => assembly != null)
                     .Select(assembly => new
                     {
                         Version = assembly.GetName().Version.ToString(),
                         Name = assembly.GetName().Name
                     });

foreach (var infos in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(infos.Name + "   " + infos.Version);
}
```

#### Update 2:

So to get it from *normal* DLLs you should take a look into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420185/how-to-get-the-version-info-of-a-dll-in-c).

Comment: Thank you .. its nice, but how to read details of legacy dlls.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused on what you actually want, but check the Assembly class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use [Assembly.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28.aspx). There is one problem, you can't unload it, so if you do it too much times your memory will be filled by garbage.

Comment: You can load assembly to an addition AppDomain so can unload them both easily

Comment: @abatishchev yes, but 1) it is much slower in terms of performance 2) cross domain calls are expensive

Comment: Maarshalling between AppDomains is a P.I.T.A :/

Comment: Right, so choose one: load to default AppDomain - quick but with high memoery cost; or - create new AppDomain - vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

If you call [AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.getassemblyname.aspx), the assembly doesn't get loaded into your appdomain.

To include subfolders, you'll likely need to write a recursive function. [Directory.GetDirectories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getdirectories.aspx) or [DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s7xk2b58.aspx) can be used to retrieve all subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Assembly.GetName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Reflection.Assembly.GetName.aspx) to get an object, where you can extract the assembly version, as one part of an assemblies name is its version.

As already mentioned above, an assembly loaded with [Assembly.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.load.aspx) cannot be unloaded and therefore remains in memory. You can however create a separate [AppDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.AppDomain.aspx), which you can unload again. Data transfer between AppDomains is possible by passing serializable objects, which is no problem for you because you just want to pass a string.

If you actually want to load the assemblies in the context of an extendable application, have a look at [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com).

Best Regards,
Oliver Hanappi

Answer (score 0):

Use [Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.reflectiononlyloadfrom.aspx)  if you don't need to execute any code from that assembly and you want only gather some info about members contained inside.