# How to get .exe file properties details in c?

Tags: c, version, executable

I am writing a c application in Visual Studio 2008, and need to grab some information from the executable to send to another application.

The info I need is what you get when you right click on an executable->Properties->Details

How can you get the "Product version" and "File version" information from .exe file in c?

and also can you set such values from Visual Studio 2008? if so how?

Specifically interested in Product version and File Version, though other version info (Product Name, etc) would be helpful as well.

Comment: Does this work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/420185/how-to-get-the-version-info-of-a-dll-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`GetFileVersionInfoSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647005%28VS.85%29.aspx), [`GetFileVersionInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647003%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), and [`VerQueryValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647464%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) should at least give you a good start.

Comment: thanks, and is there a way to set the version info from Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes -- if you're using an AppWizard generated project, it'll already have version info. Otherwise, in the resource view, right click on the project, click Add, then Resource, and choose "Version" from the list. That specific sequence is for VS 2008, but it's pretty similar (if not identical) for all recent versions, IIRC (e.g., in VS 2010, same sequence starting in the Solution Explorer).

Comment: thanks! got it... and is there a way to auto-increment this value?

Comment: @emge: I'm not aware of anything built-in to VS to auto-increment it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [VerQueryValue()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647464%28VS.85%29.aspx).