# Casting error with GetModuleFileNameW

Tags: c++, c, casting, compiler-errors

I'm trying to get the version information for a module in some C++ code (basically [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420185/how-to-get-the-version-info-of-a-dll-in-c/420314#420314)) and I'm getting compile time errors. Here's the code:

```
WCHAR fileName[MAX_PATH];
HMODULE module = GetModuleHandle(L"some-module");
DWORD size = GetModuleFileName(module, fileName, MAX_PATH);
```

And the compiler is returning:

```
    error C2664: 'GetModuleFileNameW' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'WHANDLE' to 
    'HMODULE'
    Conversion from 'void*' to pointer to non-'void' requires an explicit cast
```

What is going on here? `GetModuleHandle` returns `HMODULE` and that is the documented first parameter to `GetModuleFileName`.

Here is the compiler version for what its worth:

```
    Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.30319.01 for 80x86
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that's the right code and the right error?  `module` in the `GetModuleFileName` call is clearly already of type `HMODULE`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There must be something funky going on with your includes or your libraries, because this compiles and runs fine here:

```
// Scratch.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    WCHAR fileName[MAX_PATH];
    HMODULE module = GetModuleHandle(L"some-module");
    DWORD size = GetModuleFileName(module, fileName, MAX_PATH);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, that's what I was worried about. Which version of the compiler are you using?

Comment: I was using Visual Studio 2010 SP1 for this experiment.

Comment: It turns out that this problem was caused by the Lotus Notes C-API headers (global.h) ... gurrr!