# Read dll version from the folder in vc++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll

Suppose I have folder name **DLL_FOLDER** and the 2 dlls are in there. structure of the folder are look like-

DLL

```
a.dll      (1.0.1.0)

b.dll      (1.1.0.0)
```

Now I have to read the version of the each dll and compare it from the version information stored in the registry.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/420185/how-to-get-the-version-info-of-a-dll-in-c

Comment: @acraig5075 I have dll which were build in vc6.I have already used these method but I think it detect only .exe file .

Comment: @vikky: acraig5075 is wright, this method works for dlls.